# checking edge for circular movement

Tags: geometry, processing

I want to make my dot program turn around when they reach edge

so basically i just simply calculate 
`x = width/2+cos(a)*20;`
`y = height/2+sin(a)*20;`
it's make circular movement. so i want to make this turn around by checking the edge. i also already make sure that y reach the if condition using println command

```
class particles {
float x, y, a, r, cosx, siny;
particles() {
x = width/2; y = height/2; a = 0; r = 20;
}
void display() {
ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
}
void explode() {
a = a + 0.1;
cosx = cos(a)*r;
siny = sin(a)*r;
x = x + cosx;
y = y + siny;
}

void edge() {
if (x>width||x<0) cosx*=-1;
if (y>height||y<0) siny*=-1;
 }
}   
//setup() and draw() function

particles part;
void setup(){
size (600,400);
part = new particles();
}
void draw(){
background(40);
part.display();
part.explode();
part.edge();
}
```

they just ignore the if condition

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including a minimal `setup()` and `draw()`. The code that you have seems to be a cross between setup and draw.

Comment: sorry for that, i new in this site. they(this site) tell me to use minimal code possible to make it clear. I'll edit whole code since it was small code

Comment: The point isn't just minimal code but minimal *reproducible* code. Enough that someone can run as is and see what the problem is. In this case, the problem is likely to lie in `draw()`, which is something that you don't show at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with your check, the problem is with the fact that presumably the very next time through `draw()` you ignore what you did in response to the check by resetting the values of `cosx` and `siny`.

I recommend creating two new variables, `dx` and `dy` ("d" for "direction") which will always be either +1 and -1 and change *these* variables in response to your edge check. Here is a minimal example:

```
float a,x,y,cosx,siny;
float dx,dy;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  noFill();
  x = width/2; 
  y = height/2;
  dx = 1;
  dy = 1;
  a = 0;
}

void draw(){
  ellipse(x,y,10,10);
  cosx = dx*20*cos(a); 
  siny = dy*20*sin(a);
  a += 0.1;
  x += cosx; 
  y += siny;
  if (x > width || x < 0)
    dx = -1*dx;

  if (y > height || y < 0)
    dy = -1*dy;
}
```

When you run this code you will observe the circles bouncing off the edges:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, actually i still dont understand how this work. I mean what's the difference if i make the `cosx` it self become negative value. `cosx = cos(a)*20;` equal `1.8` multiply `cosx = cosx*-1` `cosx=-1.8` . doesnt it look the same with `cosx= -1*cos(a)*20` with same result `-1.8`.

Comment: @user196173 The problem is *when* you have the line `cosx = -1*cosx` vs. when you have `cosx = coas(a)*20` and how that relates to when you call your drawing code. Your question didn't show the relevant code (and the edited question still doesn't). The point of introducing and changing `dx` is that the change persists between frames (until you encounter the other edge) but `cosx = cos(a)*20` is (I am guessing) done each frame. Without a [mcve] (something which can run as is) I can do no more than guess.

Comment: ah i got it. i understand your reference resetting the value. so when i run `edge()` function it give me negative value, but I just resetting my value on `explode()` function which is `cosx = cos(a)*20` make it overlap the `edge()` function. thanks a lot for teaching me

Comment: @user196173  With your edits, my answer no longer reflects your code, though you could do the same approach (of using `dx` and `dy`) or perhaps drop the `edge` method entirely and move that check into the the `explode` method. It took me just a few seconds to add `dx, dy` to your class definition and it worked similarly to my screen shot.